# Create CSV File with Multiple Lines

Tags: php, csv

Okay so, I am actually trying to create a CSV File through PHP that will look like this in Excel:

> Name, Surname, Age
>
> John, Daniel, 26
>
> Mike, Daniel, 15
>
> Alison, Daniel, 66

In order to do that, I save all the details in an array like this:

```
$csvarray[0] = "name, surname, age";
```

And for the rest I use a for loop (because I don't know how many people there are), like this:

```
for($x = 1; $x <= $max; $x ++) {
$name = $_POST ['age'];
$surname = $_POST ['age'];
$age = $_POST ['age'];
$csvarray[x] = "$name, $surname, $age"; }
```

This is the code I use in order to create the CSV file and save the details:

```
$csvfile = fopen("test.csv","w");

foreach ($csvarray as $line) {
    fputcsv($csvfile,explode (',',$line));
}
fclose($file);
```

The problem is, when I open the file to check what is in there, all I see is row 0 and the last row of the final person. For example:

> Name, Surname, Age
>
> Alison, Daniel, 66

What am I doing wrong? Is there a smarter way to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$csvarray[$x] = "$name, $surname, $age";`.... in PHP, variables are prefixed with a `$`, so `$x` rather than `x`.... if you'd had error reporting enabled, it would have warned you about this

Comment: But why not build a nested array `$csvarray[$x] = [$name, $surname, $age];` then you wouldn't need to explode in your write loop either

Comment: No, @MarkBaker fixed it for me, all I had to do is use $x instead of x. Thanks